# Large circular distribution of clouds

Tags: fluid-dynamics, weather, meteorology

I've just noticed a strange circular pattern of clouds, above Netherlands, in a weather forecast website:

[image]

This image was taken from the website around 11h30, and it was the frame from 9h45 (CET). Is this a common pattern or could it have been a data acquisition/processing error?

If this is normal, how are these patterns formed?

Comment: The pattern centered over Rotterdam and stretching to the Cologne area looks too symmetrical to be natural to me.

Comment: @Countto10 - That's almost certainly interference from their radar (i.e., over the Netherlands).  The cyclone-like pattern over the UK, however, is consistent with known weather patterns.

Comment: @honeste_vivere  thanks for that, I should have thought further about the cause.   I have to say that, as I live in Ireland, with 4 different weather systems around us,  any  weather  forecast is still  comparable to examining the entrails of a chicken,  as regards reliability. :) Regards